# Intended block - invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax, block

I have been working on a code and get the expected intended block error. Could you kindly help me why it's not working?

Error line:

```
qr_os = qr_os.append(qr2.iloc[i],ignore_index=True)
```

Code:

```
d = qr2.iloc[0].to_dict()
for i in list(d.keys()): d[i] = np.nan


for i in range(len(qr2)):
    if qr2.iloc[i]['PrimaryRiskId'] not in list(aID):
        if qr2.iloc[i]['LinkageLinkType'] != 'B2B_COUNTER_TRADE':
            if qr2.iloc[i]['CreatedBy'] != 'koala_manual'\
        and qr2.iloc[i]['Book'] not in {'PIZH','SIBZ','IIBZ','OTCL','FXNG'}\
            and qr2.iloc[i]['SubCategoryValuation'] not in {'EQCertificate','EQCertificatePlus','EQCappucino','EQCliquetUnlimitedDownside'}:
             qr_rec = qr_rec.append(qr2.iloc[i],ignore_index=True)
             
d[list(d.keys())[0]] = 'records which are in cleaned QueryResults and are not in TMRActivity'
qr_rec = qr_rec.append(d,ignore_index=True)


#### QueryResults exceptions which are out of scope###

qr_os = qr2.iloc[[0,1]]

for i in range(len(qr2)):
    if qr2.iloc[i]['PrimaryRiskId'] not in list(aID):
        if qr2.iloc[i]['LinkageLinkType'] == 'B2B_COUNTER_TRADE':
            if qr2.iloc[i]['CreatedBy'] == 'koala_manual'\
        and qr2.iloc[i]['Book'] in {'PIZH','SIBZ','IIBZ','OTCL','FXNG'}\
        and qr2.iloc[i]['SubCategoryValuation'] in {'EQCertificate','EQCertificatePlus','EQCappucino','EQCliquetUnlimitedDownside'}:
            qr_os = qr_os.append(qr2.iloc[i],ignore_index=True)
            
d[list(d.keys())[0]] = 'records which are in cleaned QueryResults and are not in TMRActivity and should be treated as o/s'
qr_os = qr_os.append(d,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Please add an indentation in front of this line.

Comment: There's a difference between "intended" and "indented". Maybe this is why you don't understand the reason for the error?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code:

```
if qr2.iloc[i]['CreatedBy'] == 'koala_manual'\
    and qr2.iloc[i]['Book'] in {'PIZH','SIBZ','IIBZ','OTCL','FXNG'}\
    and qr2.iloc[i]['SubCategoryValuation'] in {'EQCertificate','EQCertificatePlus','EQCappucino','EQCliquetUnlimitedDownside'}:
        qr_os = qr_os.append(qr2.iloc[i],ignore_index=True)
```

The line

```
 if qr2.iloc[i]['CreatedBy'] == 'koala_manual'\
```

is in the same indentation level as

```
qr_os = qr_os.append(qr2.iloc[i],ignore_index=True)
```

So the problem must be there.

Comment: Thank you, it really help, I wonder if you could kindly take a look at the issue I mentioned below? Apologies if it's not the smart one